# python selenium html element select

Tags: python

*Hello first. Im try to make a bot which can make a list about your followers and Im using selenium/python for this.  Now Im tying to click followers button on my profile but I guess something goes wrong about xpath, how can I fix this.*

```
def followers(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + instagramLoginInfo.username +"/")
        sleep(1)
        followerslink = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a')
        followerslink.click()
        sleep(5)

        followers = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[role=dialog] ul").find_elements_by_css_selector("li")

        for user in followers:
            link = user.find_element_by_css_selector("a").get_attribure("href")
            print(link)
```

**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a"}
(Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)**

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help to answer you question while not reproducing your code from scratch. It will help to get an answer much faster. Thanks.